# GTK+-based graph?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk2

I want to be able to make a line graph using GTK+ but I'm unsure how to approach this. Has anyone got any hints or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/links.html) there are some C++ [libraries](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) that interface with gnuplot, which do what you are looking for and then some. It is very easy to use if you've ever used gnuplot.

Comment: Faced with the same question as the OP 5.5 years ago, I wonder why this answer was accepted? It does not answer the question! At the very least, a one-sentence-hint how the plot (created with gnuplot) could be displayed in a Gtk widget is missing.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit:**

Here are GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3 versions of that program:

- https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/tree/master/c/gtk2-graph
- https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/tree/master/c/gtk3-graph

**Original answer:**

Here's a GTK2 application using cairo to draw a simple math function:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cairo.h>

#define WIDTH   640
#define HEIGHT  480

#define ZOOM_X  100.0
#define ZOOM_Y  100.0


gfloat f (gfloat x)
{
    return 0.03 * pow (x, 3);
}

static gboolean
on_expose_event (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create (widget->window);
    GdkRectangle da;            /* GtkDrawingArea size */
    gdouble dx = 5.0, dy = 5.0; /* Pixels between each point */
    gdouble i, clip_x1 = 0.0, clip_y1 = 0.0, clip_x2 = 0.0, clip_y2 = 0.0;
    gint unused = 0;

    /* Define a clipping zone to improve performance */
    cairo_rectangle (cr, 
            event->area.x, 
            event->area.y, 
            event->area.width, 
            event->area.height);
    cairo_clip (cr);

    /* Determine GtkDrawingArea dimensions */
    gdk_window_get_geometry (widget->window, 
            &da.x, 
            &da.y, 
            &da.width, 
            &da.height, 
            &unused);

    /* Draw on a black background */
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    /* Change the transformation matrix */
    cairo_translate (cr, da.width / 2, da.height / 2);
    cairo_scale (cr, ZOOM_X, -ZOOM_Y);  

    /* Determine the data points to calculate (ie. those in the clipping zone */
    cairo_device_to_user_distance (cr, &dx, &dy);
    cairo_clip_extents (cr, &clip_x1, &clip_y1, &clip_x2, &clip_y2);
    cairo_set_line_width (cr, dx);

    /* Draws x and y axis */
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    cairo_move_to (cr, clip_x1, 0.0);
    cairo_line_to (cr, clip_x2, 0.0);
    cairo_move_to (cr, 0.0, clip_y1);
    cairo_line_to (cr, 0.0, clip_y2);
    cairo_stroke (cr);

    /* Link each data point */
    for (i = clip_x1; i < clip_x2; i += dx)
        cairo_line_to (cr, i, f (i));

    /* Draw the curve */
    cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6);
    cairo_stroke (cr);

    cairo_destroy (cr);
    return FALSE;
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *da;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Graph drawing");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    da = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), da);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (da), 
            "expose-event", 
            G_CALLBACK (on_expose_event), 
            NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I just want to add some more alternatives to this common request.

1. [libgoffice](http://freshmeat.net/projects/goffice/)
   This is the library used by **Gnumeric** and **AbiWord**, so it is actively maintained and fairly stable: one of the sanest alternative currently available. Unfortunately, there is no official home page and it lacks beginners documentation.
2. [GtkDatabox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkdatabox/)
   It recently changed the maintainer, so there is some uncertainty in the future. It used to be a good solution for rendering a lot of data in line plots.
3. [GtkExtra2](http://gtkextra.sourceforge.net/)
   This was the old de-facto standard of plotting charts in GTK+. The jump to GTK+2 seems to have been fatal to this project.
4. [GTK+ instrumentation widgets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/giw/) and [GLineGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gapcmon/files/)
   Somewhat spartans but good for simple stuff.

Other than that, a lot of projects implement internally some kind of GTK+ charting. Other than the yet cited **Gnuplot**, there is also [Gwyddion](http://gwyddion.net/documentation/libgwydgets/GraphWidgets.php) and [gretl](http://gretl.sourceforge.net/API/gretl-graphing.html). And I'm pretty sure I'm missing tons of others.

In conclusion, there is no general consensus nor a de-facto standard for charting in the GTK+ world...

Comment: Im currently having a look at how gnome-system-monitor draws its graphs, to me the way it implements it using cairo seems to be a good way to plot, plus im trying to plot in real time as well.  Thanks for you info ntd, its all taken on board.