# Can I create a histogram using Gtk in native way (no external libraries)?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gtk

I'm struggling with Google to find a native way to draw histogram (or other kind of graphs) using Gtk in C++.

Maybe I'm wrong, maybe I'm not good with research on Google... anyway it seems that there is no native way to do this. This sounds strange since there are applications built for Gnome in Gtk such as [Baobab (aka Disk Usage Analyzer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Usage_Analyzer), where there is some (circular) histogram.

I'd like standard histogram (bar plot or bar chart if you prefer).

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629099/gtk-based-graph

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm aware about gnuplot. I'm asking if there is a native way to do the job!

Comment: Did you study the source code of Baobab (which is probably free software)? It could inspire you!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no I didn't. I found around some snippets that allows me to do the job. Anyway, I prefer a native way, if there is any, in order to have a more robust implementation of my code. If there is no Gtk-Native way, then I will give up and I will use the code I found.

Comment: GTK+ does not have a builtin histogram control; sorry. You'll have to make it yourself using GtkDrawingArea and cairo.

Comment: @andlabs thanks a lot for your answer